¿Como puedo solucionar este error al instalar postgresql y abrir el pgAdmin?
Buen día,
Me podrían colaborar con algún error que este cometiendo, ya que hago los pasos que veo online para descargar el postgresql, y el visor que seria PGadmin pero me sale este error y coloco configuración del puerto, pero adjunto el que me sale por predeterminado. pero sigue ocurriendo el error así que si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido.
Gracias



Usando el administrador de tareas, revisaste si el proceso de postgresql se encuentra ejecutandose?

En esta configuración no debes usar el puerto de la base de datos. Este puerto pertenece al servidor Web que creará PGAdmin. Si quieres controlar el puerto de la aplicación Web debes seleccionar la casilla de Fixed Port.

